# Not storing expected String from a JTextArea after input is updated

Tags: java, swing, events, split, jtextarea

I have an inner class within a calculator that has working buttons. I have a `JTextArea` in which button presses will register a number 1-9 then print a new line once an operation is selected. After an operation is selected I have a boolean which will check whether to calculate the result before printing again. I have attempted to split each number and store it by using:

```
String s = textArea.getText();
String[] parts = s.split("\n|\\=|\\-|\\/|\\*|\\+");
```

While I am expecting something along the lines of

`100+`

`100=`

`200+`

I am instead running into:

`100+`

`100=`

`java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String`

To do these calculations I have used the following snippet of code:

```
if(s.length() > 0){
   if(calc == true){
      textArea.setText(textArea.getText() + "=" + "\n");
      d2 = Double.parseDouble(parts[counter]);
      result = d1 + d2;
      textArea.setText(textArea.getText() + result + buttonText + "\n");
      d1 = d2;
   }
   if(Character.isDigit(s.charAt(s.length()-1)) && calc == false){
      textArea.setText(textArea.getText() + buttonText + "\n");
      d1 = Double.parseDouble(parts[counter]);
      counter++;
      calc = true;
   }
}
```

Is there a way to store the numbers to be used after each input without running into this error?

edit: The error occurs with the line

```
Double.parseDouble(parts[counter]);
```

when removed it causes no errors but still prints normally. What I've noticed through testing with Double.parseDouble(parts[0]); it would work and return the first string input from buttons, but it seems that after this there is no more value being stored into the

```
String[] parts = s.split("\n|\\=|\\-|\\/|\\*|\\+");
```

array, it seems to be stopping there despite the additional inputs fulfilling the delimiter requirements. I am wondering if this is due to an issue with the split method not adding additional inputs into the array.

As requested I am also posted the full code here where relevant

```
class operands implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
        {   
            Object obj = event.getSource();
            JButton but = null;
            String buttonText = "";
            //casts button with object
            if(obj instanceof JButton)
            {
                but = (JButton) obj;
            }
            //sets string of text to button text
                if(but != null)
            {
                buttonText = but.getText();
            }
            String s = textArea.getText();
            //store numbers after each operand
            String[] parts = s.split("\n|\\=|\\-|\\/|\\*|\\+");
            if(s.length() > 0)
            {
                if(calc)
                    {
                        //performs calculation and returns result
                        textArea.setText(textArea.getText() + "=" + "\n");
                        d2 = Double.parseDouble(parts[counter]);
                        result = d1 + d2;
                        textArea.setText(textArea.getText() + result + buttonText + "\n");
                        d1 = d2;
                    }
                if(Character.isDigit(s.charAt(s.length()-1)) && !calc)
                {
                    //updates function to perform calculation on next operand
                    textArea.setText(textArea.getText() + buttonText + "\n");
                    d1 = Double.parseDouble(parts[counter]);
                    counter++;
                    calc = true;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: The code, you've posted here give us no hint about your problem. Please provide a [mcve], so we can find your mistake and help you. Please also provide the complete stack trace you've got. BTW: have you tried to skip all empty strings and remove leading/trailing spaces? BTW2: `if(calc == true)` is equivalent to ìf(calc)`, and `if(calc == false)` is equivalent to `if(!calc)`.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your input. I have made appropriate changes as well as more detail into my findings. All the variables are initialized locally in the outer class, and this is just an override for an event click to perform intended

Comment: Try adding **something like** this: `if(calc && !parts[counter].equals("")) { ... )`.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the fix. It seem to have prevented the error from showing, but I am still running into the problem in which the parts[counter] is not updating and adding the inputting int into array. It seems that with the new condition it wouldn't even run the code snippit anymore.

Comment: A Calculator usually keeps a running total. You recalculate the total as each operation is applied. There should be no need to parse the entire text in the text area every time a new operation is encountered.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the response. I have a running total store in the double result that should change each time.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to all those who tried to help. I have found the issue.

For the string .split() function, I had "\n" as one of the delimiters. Doing so seemed to have an issue in storing the number into the string and as a result would store an empty result into the array. Removing newline from the delimiter seemed to have solved the issue.